# How Can I calculate mean value of Random Variable

Tags: expectation, random

${\phi}_{i}$ is uniform random variable [${-\pi}, {\pi}$)

$$x =\sum _{ i }^{  }{ \frac { { a }_{ i } }{ { a }_{ 0 } } cos\left( { \phi  }_{ i } \right)  } $$

$$y =\sum _{ i }^{  }{ \frac { { a }_{ i } }{ { a }_{ 0 } } sin\left( { \phi  }_{ i } \right)  } $$

How can I calculate Expectation of the function below?
$$E\left[ 3{ y }^{ 2 }{ x }^{ 2 }-\frac { 2 }{ 3 } { y }^{ 4 } \right] $$

Comment: Well first we would want to assign some probabilities to x and y?

Answer (score 1):

Straight from definition,
$$
\mathbb{E}[Z(x,y)] = \int_0^1 Z(x(\phi),y(\phi)) f_i(\phi) d\phi,
$$
where $f(\cdot)$ is the pdf of $\phi_i$. Can you plug your functions in and evaluate?